# Does TestU01 ensure that a PRNG is cryptographically safe?

Tags: random

I was reading O'Neill's paper on the family of Permuted Congruential Generators and she states that LCGs with 88-bit input state pass the stringent BigCrush battery of tests of TestU01. My question is, if these LCGs pass BigCrush, why are they not suitable for cryptography? In general, can we say that any pseudorandom number generator that passes BigCrush is suitable for cryptography or not?

Comment: *In general, can we say that any pseudorandom number generator that passes BigCrush is suitable for cryptography or not?* NOT! A cryptographic PRNG has to be secure. There are no set of standard tests that can be done to confirm that a CSPRNG is secure. An 88-bit input state is way too little as a threshold matter.

Comment: There are things like randomizers built with quantum components, but those would not be classified as "pseudo"-random, which is the "P" in PRNG.

Comment: Doesn't TestU01 check the security of the PRNG? And if it doesn't, how can we check if our PRNG is good enough for cryptography?

Comment: *Doesn't TestU01 check the security of the PRNG?* You're misunderstanding how these randomizer tests work. The only thing such a test can tell you is that the randomizer is *definitely* no good if it fails. If it passes the test then you do **NOT** know if it's secure. The way to be assured that a randomizer is secure for cryptography is to gain confidence in it over time based on assessments from experts. Note that, for crypto, the seeding (and re-seeding) process is also integral to the security of the randomizer.

Comment: @President James K. Polk: If your comments are answering the question, you should post them as answers.